# Postgres: Select rows that do not relate in some particular way to other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to select rows from a table that, as an example, do not have child rows in the same table (determined by the value in the column **parent**)?

So, here is a simple example:

| id | value | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v1 | null |
| 2 | v2 | null |
| 3 | v3 | 1 |

As a query result of selecting all the necessary rows from the table there should be rows with ids 2 and 3.

*The row with id === 1 has child row with id === 3 since the last has value 1 in the column **parent**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self join will do the job :

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM   MyTable AS T1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS T2
          ON T1.id = T2.parent
WHERE  T2.id IS NULL
```

This is call "semi anti join".

There is many solution with operators like : NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, EXCEPT...

Comment: it seems that the query above excludes row with id === 3 and the result is rows with ids [1, 2]... No? When it's needed to have the resulting rows with the ids [2, 3] (so, the row with id === 1 to be excluded since it has corresponding value in the parent column)

Comment: At first glance, I think the `JOIN` was inverted. I should be `ON T1.ID = T2.parent`.

Comment: Reverse the table T1, T2 in the query....

Comment: @Atmo That works (ON T1.ID = T2.parent) as expected. Thanks for help.